Mounting local broker.xml to ActiveMQ Artemis container, but my local file is changed by container
I am using this RedHat's ActiveMQ Artemis image.
I have a docker-compose.yml file to run this Artemis container & I try to mount my local ./artemis/broker.xml to replace the container default one:
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    user: "root"
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: admin
      AMQ_EXTRA_ARGS: "--relax-jolokia"
      AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: true
    volumes:
      - ./artemis/broker.xml:/home/jboss/broker/etc/broker.xml
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend
...
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge

As you can see above, I am mounting the local ./artemis/broker.xml to the container path where its default broker.xml is located.  My local directory structure is like this:
docker-compose.yml
artemis/
   - broker.xml

I am also using a root user & have the AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: true environment variable for the Artemis container.
In my local ./artemis/broker.xml, the value that differs from the container's default broker.xml is this line:
<max-disk-usage>100</max-disk-usage>

The Artemis' container by default has value 90 while my local copy has value 100. So, container's default broker.xml has value like this:
<max-disk-usage>90</max-disk-usage>

When I run the container by command docker-compose up --build -d. The Artemis container is up & running successfully.
But I notice that my local broker.xml is updated by the container & the value 100 is changed to 90 in my local ./artemis/broker.xml.
I mean I expected the broker.xml inside the container should be changed but it behaves completely the other way around that the container changes my local broker.xml after it is up and running.
Why it behaves like that? How can I have the Artemis container mount my local ./artemis/broker.xml to replace the container's default one?


========== UPDATE ==========
I tried @Domenico Francesco's answer for mounting a full broker instance folder using AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: false as the environment variable for the container, my docker-compose.yml looks like this:
version: "3"
services:
  artemis:
    image: quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker
    user: "root"
    environment:
      AMQ_USER: admin
      AMQ_PASSWORD: admin
      AMQ_EXTRA_ARGS: "--relax-jolokia"
      AMQ_RESET_CONFIG: false
    volumes:
      - ./artemis/broker.xml:/home/jboss/broker/etc/broker.xml
    ports:
      - "5672:5672"
      - "61616:61616"
      - "8161:8161"
    networks:
      - backend
...
networks:
  backend:
    driver: bridge


Then, run docker-compose up --build -d, the Artemis container fails to run with error:
2024-06-27 21:19:50 Running Broker
2024-06-27 21:19:50 /opt/amq/bin/launch.sh: line 49: /home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis: No such file or directory


The launch script of quay.io/artemiscloud/activemq-artemis-broker reset all files in /home/jboss/broker/ by default unless you set AMQ_RESET_CONFIG=false.
To set a custom value for max-disk-usage you have 2 alternatives mounting a full broker instance folder with AMQ_RESET_CONFIG=false or using a broker properties file:
Create a file with the following broker properties:
maxDiskUsage=90

Mount the file with the broker properties in the container, i.e.
    volumes:
      - ./artemis/broker.properties:/home/jboss/extra/broker.properties

Set the system property broker.properties, i.e.
    environment:
      JAVA_ARGS_APPEND: -Dbroker.properties=/home/jboss/extra/broker.properties

To customize the login.config file you have 2 alternatives mounting a full broker instance folder with AMQ_RESET_CONFIG=false or setting the system property java.security.auth.login.config to a custom value:
Mount the custom login.config file in the container, i.e.
    volumes:
      - ./artemis/login.config:/home/jboss/extra/login.config

Set the system property java.security.auth.login.config, i.e.
    environment:
      JAVA_ARGS_APPEND: -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/home/jboss/extra/login.config


Thanks! I also need to mount local ./artemis/login.config to replace the container's /home/jboss/broker/etc/login.config, since I need to update the default content of that file. How to achieve that?

I tried your answer, but when run the container, I get error:
2024-06-27 21:19:50 Running Broker 2024-06-27 21:19:50 /opt/amq/bin/launch.sh: line 49: /home/jboss/broker/bin/artemis: No such file or directory
Please check my updated post.

@user842225 in your updated compose.yml I only see a volume for the file broker.xml while you should mount a full broker instance folder with AMQ_RESET_CONFIG=false, this is why you are getting the error artemis: No such file or directory

@user842225 I updated my answer to describe a solution to customize the login.config file without setting AMQ_RESET_CONFIG=false.
